# Command glob : type

Tags: tcl

Here my command :

```
foreach fic [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir -types {f d r} *] {
    set infofile [list [file tail $fic] [file mtime $fic] [file atime $fic]]
    # ...
}
```

Only I have an error : **couldn't read directory "/Users/..." permission denied...**
My solution is to add this command : `file readable`

```
foreach fic [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir -types {f d} *] {
    if {![file readable $fic]} continue
    set infofile [list [file tail $fic] [file mtime $fic] [file atime $fic]]
    # ...
}
```

I thought when I added the `r` -type this kind of error did not appear.
It’s a misunderstanding of the documentation ?

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: @Brad Lanam Mac & Windows

Comment: I think we need to know what the exact permissions were for the file/directory that failed and its parent directory.

Comment: I think the types are an OR of the conditions (“file” _or_ “directory” _or_ “readable”). Also, the permissions for access control on Windows are _very_ complicated — there are aspects to them that I don't understand, but at least I know that I don't understand — so it's better to just handle the fact that `open` can fail. The filtering in `glob` is for efficiency, not a final decision…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions on Windows are complex, to the point where you can only be really sure that you've got permission to read a file immediately after you've successfully opened it for reading. The indications from `glob` and `file readable` are not definitive. This is the case on other operating systems, and in any case there's a race condition: the user could change the permissions between checking with `file readable` and calling some other operation. Because of that, while you can use `glob -type r`, you should not rely on it. It simply can't be guaranteed to be correct.

The fix for this? Handle errors from calls properly.

```
foreach fic [glob -nocomplain -dir $dir -types {f d r} *] {
    try {
        # More efficient than calling [file mtime] and [file atime] separately
        file stat $fic data
    } on error {} {
        # Couldn't actually handle the file. Ignore
        continue
    }
    set infofile [list [file tail $fic] $data(mtime) $data(atime)]
    # ...
}
```

Comment: `r` is it useful ?

Comment: Actually, I think `r` is not that useful.  Windows uses access control lists, Linux might have access control lists, and `r` won't work for those.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Lanam , I believe that too